# How does NAT Stitching work?

Tags: cisco, firewall, nat, netflow

While reading about CISCO NetFlow Analysis I came up with a term named `NAT Stitching`.

I understand `Flow Stitching` which join same type of inbound and outbound connection.

But can't find anything discrete about `NAT Stitching` except the following,

> NAT stitching: Unify the NAT information from inside the firewall with information from outside the firewall to pinpoint which IPs and users inside the network are responsible for a particular action

So how it work in detail? Is it a process/protocol or a specific type of NAT?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must remember that a flow using NAT will look like two different flows: a flow pre-NAT, and a flow post-NAT. This is because NAT is changing one or more of the addresses in the packets. This can present a distorted view of your flows.

As Cisco explains it, NAT stitching will stitch the (apparently) separate flows to give you the single flow view:

> Exporting NetFlow from the NAT devices will stitch both pre & post NAT
>   flows together.

The Cisco Press book *NetFlow for Cybersecurity* goes into more detail:

> Lancope’s StealthWatch solution supports a feature called network
>   address translation (NAT) stitching. NAT stitching uses data from
>   network devices to combine NAT information from inside a firewall (or
>   a NAT device) with information from outside the firewall (or a NAT
>   device) to identify which IP addresses and users are part of a
>   specific flow. A great feature of the StealthWatch solution is its
>   ability to perform “NetFlow deduplication.” This feature allows you to
>   deploy several NetFlow collectors within your organization without
>   worrying about double or triple counting the traffic.